# Summing N normal distributions

Tags: r, distribution, convolution

I am trying to determine the distribution of the sum of N univariate distributions.
Can you suggest a function that allows me to dynamically input any N number of distributions?

This works:

```
library(distr)
var1 <- Norm(mean=14, sd=1)
var2 <- Norm(mean=10, sd=1)
var3 <- Norm(mean=9, sd=1)
conv <- convpow(var1+var2+var3,1)
```

This (obviously) doesn't work since pasting the list together creates a messy character string, however this is the framework for my ideal function:

```
convolution_multi <- function(mean_list = c(14,10,9,10,50)){
  distribution_list <- lapply(X = mean_list, Norm, sd=1)
  conv_out <- convpow(paste(distribution_list,collapse="+"),1)
  return(conv_out)
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `convpow` is wrong function to call. It convolutes N identical univariates. You want sum of N different (though similar) univariates, as far as I understand

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Sure but they're also calling it with N=1.  They aren't doing anything wrong really - they just aren't doing anything at all there.  I mention that in my answer.

Comment: Why are you writing a program for this?  The well-known analytical answer is that the sum of normals is normal.

Comment: @Dason Yes, you're right, I agree, but author assumes it is doing something. And it is really wrong function to call, there are other FFT-based convolution packages

Comment: @pjs - I agree. If this is literally the actual task then there are much more direct ways to approach the problem but it's also possible this is just a simplified illustration of the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` to repeatedly add each RV to one another.  After that you can use convpow

```
new_var <- Reduce("+", distribution_list)
convpow(new_var, 1)
```

With that being said the call to convpow does absolutely nothing here.

```
> identical(convpow(new_var, 1), new_var)
[1] TRUE
```